# Creating a site on rails where users will be able to join groups and be able to interact with the group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I recently started creating a site where users will be able to join groups and be able to interact with the group.  So far I have used devise for the users but I'm now wondering what do I use to create user profiles and even the groups profile. This is my first rails application and I just need some guidance on where to go from here?  What tools will I need?  What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to pre-populate the user and groups table?  Or are you wondering how site visitors will go about creating their own user accounts and groups?

Comment: Wondering how to code so that a user can create a profile and be able to join groups together and edit the groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails is the only tool you need. First you'll need to create the other models in your application. From your description I see a UserProfile and a Group. Rails' generator command will stub those out for you:

```
$ rails generate model UserProfile
$ rails generate model Group
$ rails generate model Membership
```

Now you will have user_profile.rb and group.rb in your app/models directory, as well as migrations in db/migrate/*create*.rb. Next you'll need to tell rails what fields to create in the database by [editing the migration script](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). You are free to include whatever you wish here, but you will at least want foreign keys to relate your data.

```
def CreateUserProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
    create_table :user_profiles do |t|
        t.belongs_to :user
        ...
```

and

```
def CreateMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration
    create_table :memberships
        t.belongs_to :user
        t.belongs_to :group
        ...
```

Now you can execute your migrations to create the database tables for you:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

And you can use ActiveRecord association class methods to define those relationships in code, so that Rails will take care of the SQL for you.

```
app/models/membership.rb

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
end

app/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user_profile
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
    ...
end

app/models/group.rb

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

app/models/user_profile.rb

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you have all the tools in place that you need to give users profiles:

```
UserProfile.create(:user => User.first, :attr => "value", ...)
```

Or to put a user in a group:

```
group = Group.create(:name => "Group 1")
group.users << User.first
```

Use tools when they save you time, but learn to use the tool on which they all depend first–Rails. Check out the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), they are excellent.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Great answer showing the many-to-many using :through.

Comment: wow Sam C thank you.  I will try this out and see how it goes.